# An option to display newest unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to display unanswered questions ordered by post date (newest unanswered first)?

Browsing unanswered question using the ['no answers'](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) tab (based on vote count) does not make sense for less common tags, as it's hard to find questions that can be answered or are worth answering. There are also hundreds of up-voted:

1. questions with answer in comments
2. questions with right answers but not accepted by the questioner
3. questions waiting for the questioner to clarify
4. outdated questions

On the other hand ['newest'](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) contains answered and accepted questions, which i don't want to either answer or see.

Comment: Well, that's just not true. Unanswered questions are questions that have *no upvoted or accepted answers*, which is what the "newest" subtab will give you. If you actually see questions with accepted answers in there, it's a bug or a caching issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3a0 works in general, but it seems the search results are cached and so you see some questions with answers at the very newest end of the search.

Comment: unanswered-newest tab displays questions with *no upvoted answeres*, so questions with answers are *unanswered* as long as the answers have no votes. See:  http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php?tab=newest

Comment: @awoodland is there any way to skip those cached results?

Comment: @Flexo why not post this as answer? The caching is pretty minor issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by combining a few search operators carefully, a direct link:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3a0

Which is searching for `answers:0`, `is:question` and `closed:0`.

The search results are cached so you may see some questions with answers at the newer end of the results sometimes.

You can throw in `votes:5` as well for example if you want to only view questions with at least 5 votes.

Comment: I've been looking for this since forever!