# Organize unanswered with no answers (accepted or otherwise) and newest?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I was wondering if there is a way to organize unanswered questions by both newest and those without an answer (either accepted or otherwise)? [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122898/an-option-to-display-newest-unanswered-questions) is a really similar question but not quite the same thing. What I would like is something akin to Windows Explorer where you can first organize by date, then by type and the 'date' part sticks even after it is organized into type. I would love it be able to 'pass on' the last organization method I used. I hope that makes sense.

Also I should mention that this may fall under the cost/benefit section of how much coding it takes to provide a service that not many people would use. Unfortunately I don't do a lot of web programming so I have no idea how much of a pain in the rear this would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the search functionality with the following query:

```
[your tag] answers:0
```

and then in the search results click the "Newest" tab:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. I probably should have been able to find that. Also good luck in the moderator election (I literally just voted for you before you answered this question).

Comment: @tmwoods The search is quite powerful with advanced features. You can expand the "Advanced search tips" feature in the sidebar to see more. And thank you!

Comment: Aaah, never saw that before. I will definitely be using that a lot more :)